# Get all user gd's of the users the person doesn't follow

Tags: sql

I have made a start to a social media app where users can follow and unfollow users for now. But I need a query to display the users the user doesn't follow. I was trying everything I could but just couldn't find the right solution. Could anybody help me out?

My two tables are looking like this:
[image: My tables look like the following:]

In the second table in user_gd will be the gd stored of a user who follows another user.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is pretty hard to read.  But the idea is basically `not exists` or something similar:

```
select u.*
from users u
where not exists (select 1
                  from userFollows uf
                  where uf.followed_userid = u.userid and
                        uf.userid = ?
                 );
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the user you care about.

Comment: Thanks for your help man! I think I got it I will try it right now. I will keep you updated.